# windows sdk 7.1 64-bit build CloseHandle apparently not in kernel32.lib

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-7-x64

I have installed SDK 7.1 and am attempting a port of a C/C++ project from MinGW (32-bits) to the VC 2010 that comes with SDK 7.1 at 64 bits. I am compiling in the command line environment set up for the SDK when it was installed.

I got all the files to compile, but linking defeated me, both when I set up a build with static linking of the C/C++ run-time, and when I set up an alternate build with dynamic linking of the C/C++ run-time.

For example Kernel32.lib is a part of my linkage, and it's here, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64\Kernel32.Lib that I confirmed it's being retrieved from, and yet the following linkage error is one of the many reported by both builds.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CloseHandle@4

How can these linkage problems be resolved? There is no other x64 Kernel32.lib in the SDK or with the VC 2010 that came along with it.

Comment: Are you sure that you're compiling/linking for x64? The `@4` in `__imp__CloseHandle@4` wouldn't be there if that was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the correct command line environment, which can be set up by calling `%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat x64` from a command prompt if VS 2010 is installed, then the following simple program can be compiled with just `cl test.cpp`.  `kernel32.lib` is linked in automatically since all Windows applications require it:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h;
    CloseHandle(h);
}
```

It sounds like you are using the 32-bit compiler and specifying the 64-bit kernel32.lib explicitly, which I can reproduce.  Note the banner "32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler...":

```
C:\>cl test.cpp -link "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Kernel32.Lib"
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
c:\test.cpp(6) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'h' used
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Kernel32.Lib"
test.obj
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CloseHandle@4 referenced in function _main
```